# Correct Approach WP Custom Taxonomy and Categories

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting

I have number of categories based on different basketball leagues `League A, League B, League C` and so on. What I'm trying to do is for each league to have a custom taxonomy for each season `2006-2007,2007-2008,2008-2009` so I can show the posts only for that season `Category: League A -> Season: 2006-2007 -> Posts`.

So far I've created the following taxonomy for *post* Post Type:

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_seasons' );

function create_seasons() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'                           => 'Seasons',
        'singular_name'                  => 'Season',
        'search_items'                   => 'Search Seasons',
        'all_items'                      => 'All Seasons',
        'edit_item'                      => 'Edit Season',
        'update_item'                    => 'Update Season',
        'add_new_item'                   => 'Add New Season',
        'new_item_name'                  => 'New Season Name',
        'menu_name'                      => 'Seasons',
        'view_item'                      => 'View Season',
        'popular_items'                  => 'Popular Season',
        'separate_items_with_commas'     => 'Separate Season with commas',
        'add_or_remove_items'            => 'Add or remove Season',
        'choose_from_most_used'          => 'Choose from the most used seasons',
        'not_found'                      => 'No seasons found'
    );

    register_taxonomy(
        'seasons',
        'post',
        array(
            'label' => __( 'Season' ),
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'labels' => $labels,
            'public' => true,
            'show_in_nav_menus' => false,
            'show_tagcloud' => false,
            'show_admin_column' => true,
            'rewrite' => array(
                'slug' => 'seasons'
            )
        )
    );
}
```

Now if I want to show all posts from category `League A` during the season taxonomy `2008-2009` I can use the URL parameter `?seasons=2008-2009`. Full URL `http://localhost/site/category/league-a/?seasons=2008-2009`

What bothers me is that I want to show as a default the posts from the current season `2019-2020` without using the URL parameter `?seasons=2019-2020` for each category.

Example:
`http://localhost/site/category/league-a/ -> Show posts from seasons taxonomy 2019-2020 only`.

Is there a way to make this work? Rewrite rule?

Also do you think my approach is correct with what I'm trying to do?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think there are multiple ways to achive that. My suggestion would be to create a custom query on your term archive page.

Please have a look here first: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

In Wordpress you can create your custom `category-{term}.php` page, which in your case would be called `category-league-a.php`. Make a copy of your category.php in your theme folder, or use an example out of wordpress themes (i.e. twentynineteen), and copy the code.

Inside of your new archive page (WP will recognize it automatically) remove the post loop. You now create your own post query with your taxonomy term.

Have a look at: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/

You get all posts that have a certain category term and a seasons term.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'league-a',
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'seasons',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => '2019-2020',
        ),
    ),
);
$current_season_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

You can now loop through your posts:

```
<?php
// The Loop
if ( $current_season_query ->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $current_season_query ->have_posts() ) {
        $current_season_query ->the_post();
            // echo get_the_title().'<br>'; or whatever
    }
    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();
} else {
    // no posts found
}
?>
```

It is important that you reset the post data to the orignal query, as it is done in the code above. Otherwise you could get in conflict with other queries on your page.

So you now have defined the page template for your category term. You created a custom query to only show the posts that additionally have the taxonomy term of the current season.

Hope this helps!

---

EDIT: Using only one category page template for all terms

You can also use variables in your tax_query `'category'` and `'terms'`.

```
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => $current_category,
```

and

```
        'taxonomy' => 'seasons',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => $current_season,
```

In the `$current_category` you save the slug or your current viewing category term and in `$current_season` the slug of your taxonomy term.

---

### Other solution: Check if there is a parameter in the url string

But it now comes to my mind that it would be another solution to look for the parameter in the url and only change the query if there is no parameter set. This way you just need one single `category.php` which you have to adjust a litte bit:

### 1. Get the parameter form the url

```
global $wp;
// Get current page url
$current_url = home_url( add_query_arg( array(), $wp->request ) );
// Parse the URL to get array which contains its components
$url_components = parse_url($current_url);
// parse_str() function to parse the string passed via URL
parse_str($url_components['query'], $params);
```

### 2. Check if parameter is not set and use another WP_Query in this case

```
if(!isset($params['seasons'])) {
    $current_season_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    // your code
}
else {
    // unchanged WP_Query, standard post loop in archive file
}
```

Before the `if` you define the new WP_query as described in the first code block of this answer. In the `else` you put your standard post loop.

This way you only have to make changes to your `category.php` and not have to make files for all the category terms.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the problem with this method is that I have 45 Leagues so I think is not efficient to create 45 different `category` templates. The other issue is that what If I want to navigate to previous seasons `http://localhost/site/category/league-a/?seasons=2018-2019` it still shows the posts from `?seasons=2019-2020`.

Comment: Just had another idea: checking the url for parameters! Maybe it can help you. Please take a look at my edited answer.